# what are the steps/strategy to analyze and improve performance of an embedded system

Tags: c, performance, embedded

I will break down this question in to sub questions. I am confused if I should ask them separately or in one question. So I will just stick to one SO question.

1. What are generally the steps to analyze and improve performance of C applications?
2. Do these steps change if I am developing for an embedded system?
3. What tools are out there which can help me?

Recently I have been given a task to improve the performance of our product on ARM11 platform. I am relatively new to this field of embedded systems and need gurus here on SO to help me out.

Comment: Is there an OS?  What is it?  What compiler/toolchain are you using? Do you have spare GPIO?  Do you have working simulator?  _Embedded_ is a big field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply changing compilers can improve your C performance for the same source code by many times over.  GCC has not necessarily gotten better for performance over the years, for some programs gcc 3.x produces much tighter code than 4.x.  Back when I had access to the tools, ARMs compiler produced significantly better code than gcc.  As much as 3 or 4 times faster.  LLVM has caught up to GCC 4.x and I suspect will pass gcc by in terms of performance and overall use for cross compiling embedded code.  Try different versions of gcc, 3.x and 4.x if you are using gcc.  Metaware's compiler and arms adt ran circles around gcc3.x, gcc3.x will give gcc4.x a run for its money with arm code, for thumb code gcc4.x is better and for thumb2 (which doesnt apply to you) gcc4.x also better.  Remember I have not said a word about changing a single line of code (yet).

LLVM is capable of full program optimization in addition to infinitely more tuning knobs than gcc.  Despite that the code generated (ver 27) is only just catching up to the current gcc 4.x in terms of performance for the few programs I tried.  And I didnt try the n factoral number of optimization combinations (optimize on the compile step, different options for each file, or combine two files or three files or all files and optimize those bundles, my theory is do no optimization on the C to bc steps, link all the bc together then do a single optimization pass on the whole program, the allow the default optimization when llc takes it to the target).

By the same token simply knowing your compiler and the optimizations can greatly improve the performance of the code without having to change any of it.  You have an ARM11 arr you compiling for arm11 or generic arm?  You can gain a few to a dozen percent by telling the compiler specifically which architecture/family (armv6 for example) over the generic armv4 (ARM7) that is often chosen as the default.  Knowing to use -O2 or -O3 if you are brave.

It is often not the case but switching to thumb mode can improve performance for specific platforms.  Doesnt apply to you but the gameboy advance is a perfect example, loaded with non-zero wait state 16 bit busses.  Thumb has a handful of a percent overhead because it takes more instructions to do the same thing, but by increasing the fetch times, and taking advantage of some of the sequential read features of the gba thumb code can run significantly faster than arm code for the same source code.

having an arm11 you probably have an L1 and maybe L2 cache, are they on?  Are they configured?  Do you have an mmu and is your heavy use memory cached?  or are you running zero wait state memory and dont need a cache and should turn it off?  In addition to not realizing that you can take the same source code and make it run many times faster by changing compilers or options, folks often dont realize that when you use a cache simply adding a single up to a few nops in your startup code (as a trick to adjust where code lands in memory by one, two, a few words) you can change your codes execution speed by as much as 10 to 20 percent.  Where those cache line reads hit in heavily used functions/loops makes a big difference.  Even saving one cache line read by adjusting where the code lands is noticeable (cutting it from 3 to 2 or 2 to 1 for example).

Knowing your architecture, both the processor and your memory environment is where the tuning if any would start.  Most C libraries if you are high level enough to use one (I often dont use a C library as I run without an operating system and with very limited resources) both in their C code and sometimes add some assembler to make bottleneck routines like memcpy, much faster.  If your programs are operating on aligned 32 or even better 64 bit addresses, and you adjust even if it means using a handful of bytes more memory for every structure/array/memcpy to be an integral multiple of 32 bits or 64 bits you will see noticeable improvements (if your code uses structs or copies data in other ways).  In addition to getting your structures (if you use them, I certainly dont with embedded code) size aligned, even if you waste memory, getting elements aligned, consider using 32 bit integers for every element instead of bytes or halfwords.  Depending on your memory system this can help (it can hurt too btw).  As with the GBA example above looking at specific functions that either by profiling or intuition you know are not being implemented in a manner that takes advantage of your processor or platform or libraries you may want to turn to assembler either from scratch or compiling from C initially then disassembling and hand tuning.  Memcpy is a good example you may know your systems memory performance and may chose to create your own memcpy specifically for aligned data, copying 64 or 128 or more bits per instruction.

Likewise mixing global and local variables can make a noticeable performance difference.  Traditionally folks are told never to use globals, but in embedded this isnt necessarily true, depends on how deeply embedded and how much tuning and speed and other factors you are interested in.  This is a touchy subject and I may get flamed for it, so I will leave it at that.

The compiler has to burn and evict registers in order to make function calls, plus if you use local variables a stack frame may be required, so function calls are expensive, but at the same time, depending on the code within a function that has now grown in size by avoiding functions, you may create the problem you were trying to avoid, evicting registers to re-use them.  Even a single line of C code can make the difference between all the variables in a function fits in registers to having to start evicting a bunch of registers.  For functions or segments of code where you know you need some performance gain compile and disassemble (and look at register usage, how often it fetches memory or writes to memory).  You can and will find places where you need to take a well used loop and make it its own function even though the function call has a penalty because by doing that the compiler can better optimize the loop and not evict/reuse registers and you get an overall net gain.  Even a single extra instruction in a loop that goes around hundreds of times is a measurable performance hit.

Hopefully you already know to absolutely not compile for debug, turn all of the compile for debug options off.  You may already know that code compile for debug that runs without bugs doesnt mean it is debugged, compiling for debug and using debuggers hide bugs leaving them as time bombs in your code for your final compile for release.  Learn to always compile for release and test with the release version both for performance and finding bugs in your code.

Most instruction sets do not have a divide function.  Avoid using divides or modulo in your code as much as humanly possible they are performance killers.  Naturally this is not the case for powers of two, to save the compiler and to mentally avoid divides and modulos try to use shifts and ands.  Multplies are easier and more often found in instruction sets, but are still costly.  This is a good case to write assembler to do your multiplies instead of letting the C copiler do it.  The arm multiply is a 32bit * 32bit = 32 bit so to do accurate math without overflowing there has to be extra C code wrapped around the multiply, if you already know you wont overflow, burn the registers for a function call and do the multiply in assembler (for the arm).

Likewise most instruction sets do not have a floating point unit, with yours you might, even so avoid float if at all possible.  If you have to use float that is a whole other pandora's box of performance issues.  Most folks dont see the performance problems with code as simple as this:

```
float a,b;

...

a = b * 7.0;
```

The rest of the problem is not understanding floating point accuracy and how good or bad the C libraries are just trying to get your constants into floating point form.  Again float is a whole other long discussion on performance problems.

I am a product of Michael Abrash (I actually have a print copy of zen of assembly language) and the bottom line is time your code.  Come up with an accurate way to time the code, you may think you know where the bottlenecks are and you may think you know your architecture but trying different things even if you think they are wrong, and timing them you may find and eventually have to figure out the error in your thinking.  Adding nops to start.S as a final tuning step is a good example of this, all the other work you have done for performance can be instantly erased by not having a good alignment with the cache, this also means re-arranging functions within your source code so that they land in different places in the binary image.  I have seen 10 to 20 percent swings of speed increase and decrease as a result of cache line alignments.

Answer (score 1):

1. Code Review:

   [What are good code review techniques ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141916/what-are-the-good-code-review-walkthrough-techniques)

   Static and dynamic analysis of the code.

   Tools for static analysis: Sparrow, Prevent, [Klockworks](http://www.klocwork.com/)

   Tools for dynamic analysis : [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), [purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/)

   [Gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html) allows you to learn where your program spent its time and which functions called which other functions while it was executing.
2. Steps are same
3. Apart from what is listed is point 1, there are tools like [memcheck](http://v.mahon.free.fr/pro/freeware/memcheck/) etc. 
   There is a big list [here](http://open-tube.com/12-source-code-profilers-for-cc) based on platform

Answer (score 1):

Phew!! Quite a big question!

> What are generally the steps to
>   analyze and improve performance of C
>   applications?

As well as other static code analysers mentioned here there is a fairly cheap version called [PC-Lint](http://www.gimpel.com/) which has been around for ages.  Sometimes throws up lots of errors and warnings for one error but by the end of it you'll be happy and know waaaaay more about C/C++ because of it.

With all code analysers some of the issues may be more structural to the code so best to start analysing it from day 1 of coding; running analysis on old software may swamp you with issues which may take a while to untangle, best to keep it clean from the beginning.

But code analysers will not catch all logical errors, i.e. it doesn't do what you want it to do!  These are best done by code reviews first, then testing.  Performance is often improved by by trying to keep the algorithms as simple as possible, keeping instructions in loops tight, possibly unrolling loops (your compiler optimisations may do this), use of fast caches when accessing data which is slow to get.

Code reviews can raise a lot of issues from lots of other peoples eyes looking at it.  Don't get too many people, try to get 3 other people if possible, sometimes junior developers ask the most insightful questions like, "why are we doing this?".

Testing can be roughly split into two sections, automated and manual.  Automated testing requires effort producing test handlers for functions/units but once run can be run again and again very quickly.  Manual testing requires planning, self-discipline to perform them all to the required, imagination to think up of scenarios that may impair performance and you have to be observant (you may have passed the test but the 'scope trace has a bit of an anomaly before/after the test).

> "Do these steps change if I am
>   developing for an embedded system?"

Performance ananlysis can be different on embedded systems to applications systems; with the very broad brush that "embedded" now covers it depends how hardware-centric you are.  It can be done using profilers, if you want a more cheap and chearful method then use test output pins to measure sections of code, or measure them with breakpoints on simulators that come with the development environment.

Make sure that not just a typical length of task is measured but also a maximum, as that is where one task may start impeding on other tasks and your scheduled tasks are not completed in time.

> What tools are out there which can
>   help me?

Simulators on the IDEs, static analysis tools, dynamic analysis tools, but most of all you and other humans getting the requirements right, decent reviewing (of code and testing) and thorough testing (automated and manual).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

My experiences.

1. Function calls are slow, eliminate with macros or inlined methods. Look at the disassembler listing to see.
2. If using GCC, mark optimized sections with `#pragma GCC optimize("O3")` or compile them separately.
3. Play with different combinations of applying the inline attribute (basically find a balance between size and speed).

Answer (score 0):

It is a difficult question to be answered shortly since various techniques have been proposed such as flowchart and state diagram,so you can take a look at some titles:

ARM System-on-Chip Architecture, 2nd Edition -- Steve Furber

ARM System Developer's Guide - Designing and Optimizing System Software -- Andrew N. Sloss, Dominic Symes, Chris Wright & John Rayfield

The Definitive Guide to the ARM Cortex-M3 --Joseph Yiu

C Programming for Embedded Systems --Kirk Zurell

Embedded C -- Michael J. Pont

Programming Embedded Systems in C and C++ --Michael Barr

An Embedded Software Primer --David E, Simon

Embedded Microprocessor Systems 3rd Edition --Stuart Ball

Global Specification and Validation of Embedded Systems - Integrating Heterogeneous Components --G. Nicolescu & A.A Jerraya

Embedded Systems: Modeling, Technology and Applications --Gunter Hommel & Sheng Huanye

Embedded Systems and Computer Architecture --Graham Wilson

Designing Embedded Hardware --John Catsoulis

Answer (score -1):

1. You have to use a profiler. It will help you identify your application's bottleneck(s). Then focus on improving the functions you spend the most time in and the ones you call the most. Repeat this procedure until you're satisfied with your application performance.
2. No they don't.
3. Depending on the platform you're developing onto :

   Windows : AMD Code Analyst, VTune, Sleepy

   Linux : valgrind / callgrind / cachegrind

   Mac : the Xcode profiler is quite good.

Try to find a profiler for the architecture you actually work on.

Comment: 2 -- they may somewhat if you are targeting something that is not Windows, Linux, Mac, or other desktop class OS.  They change much more when you can't run your code on your desktop and even more when you have no serial port, extra gpio, or decent ICE.

Comment: Your answers are Pc specific so question 2. is yes.